# What type of connection is this?

Tags: connector, lcd

I pulled apart an older augen netbook that ran windows CE. I was wondering what type of connecter this is. I just got my Raspberry Pi in the mail and was looking for a way to connect it for a project I have in mind. It did fit in the DSI, but with the second connector I am completely lost.

On the display there are some numbers, but a quick google search didn't yield anything.

BACK OF METAL DISPLAY CASING

```
H-T070L-18A-Q
H-T070L18A0009000000029687
```

ON THE RIBBON

```
LD91016023MTBF3
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's an [FFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_flat_cable) (Flexible Flat Cable) cable. Similar to FPC (Flexible Printed Circuit) which it is often mentioned with.

You can buy the necessary connectors from places like Mouser, Farnell, etc. Here is the selection from [Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/ffc-fpc).

If you can't find any datasheet or details, you will have to count the connections and measure pitch (distance between each copper pad) to figure out what connector you require. If you provide the info (close up photo against ruler would help too) we can help you select the right one.

Comment: After I get off work I will edit this post with a picture of it up against the ruler. So far though GREAT info!